# Get the first of many similar strings

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, grep

I have strings of the form

```
A-XXX
A-YYY
B-NNN
A-ZZZ
B-MMM
C-DDD
```

However, I want to get the first occurrence of every string before the hyphen. So the solution here would be:

```
A-XXX
B-NNN
C-DDD
```

How can I do this with bash tools? I tried `uniq`, but I can't set the "similarity-pattern" there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will this suffice?

```
cat uwe
A-XXX
A-YYY
B-NNN
A-ZZZ
B-MMM
C-DDD
$ awk -F'-' '!a[$1]{print $0;a[$1]++}' uwe
A-XXX
B-NNN
C-DDD
```

EDIT:

One can actually shorten that to the slightly more cryptic:

```
$ awk -F'-' '!a[$1]++' uwe
A-XXX
B-NNN
C-DDD
```

What we do is to tell awk `-` is the field separator; `!a[$1]` tells awk to execute the following commands (with nothing given print is the default), and post increment the array that checks whether a value was seen.

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you so much, I should really go into learning awk more.

Comment: Solltest du wirklich ;) (you really should!)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '1!G;/^\([^-]*-\).*\n\1/!P;h' file
```

The general idea is to compare the current line with all previous lines and by using pattern matching, only print the current line if there is no match on a previous key.

The first line will always be printed. From the second line onwards, the previous line(s) are appended to the current line, using the `G` command and the first or current line only printed using the `P` command if there is no key match using the `/^\(^-]*-\).*\n\1/!` command. The current line and the appended line(s) are then stored in the hold space,using the `h` command, ready for the next line.

N.B. The key is defined by characters from the start of a line, upto and including the character `-`. Thus the regexp `^[^-]*-` matches such a key. Also note that the key is collected as a group `\(...\)` and later referenced as `\1` this allows strings of characters to be referred to at a later point in the same regexp. In this case the key at the start of the current line is matched with any such key in previous lines.